# Error: The layout "basic" in layout-land has no declaration in the base layout folder — but I really don't need it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My application has `layout-land/basic.xml` and `layout-port/basic.xml` files. Why do I need one in `layout/`?

Is there something I can do to make Android Studio not complain here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are an override system.  You generally wouldn't put one in layout-land and one in layout-port.  Generally you put one or the other in the base directory, then do one of the two layout-orientation folders as an override.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much what I expected. I'll just move all of the "layout-port" entries into "layout" and call it good. I was hoping there was a way to tell Android Studio to ignore this warning. I suppose if they eventually invented some third kind of layout that wasn't portrait or landscape, things would break for lack of a base layout.